# Error en firebase database:push

Tags: firebase

Intento subir un archivo .json a firebase por medio de firebase tools

$firebase database:push /ruta/firebase <<< miarchivo.json

Y no me funciona busque en google ejemplos y no hay. Y la documentacion de firebase no explica como usarlo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ya encontre el error. Funciona pero sin los <<<